set the returned data of getServerSideProps in state, nextjs 13 pages router
what are the differences (SEO-wise) between using the raw data fetched in getServerSideProps and set in inside HTML (JSX) and setting the data in the state first and then using it in HTML (JSX)?
let's say the returned data of getServerSideProps is the string "Hello"
if I use the raw data and put it in HTML and if I see page sources (using control + U in Chrome browser),
I will see the html : <h1>Hello</h1>
but if I set the data inside the state first and then use it inside the html I won't see the h1 tag with data,
instead I only see my data (in page sources) inside a script tag as page props!
like this:
<script id="__NEXT_DATA__" type="application/json">{"props":{"pageProps":"whatever data"}"}</script>
is it bad for SEO?
should I not do it when I want my page to be SEO friendly?
here is the code for the second approach:
export default function MyPage({ data }:{ data:string }) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(data) // or maybe use useEffect instead
  return(<h1>{value}</h1>)
}

// getServerSideProps code that returns props: { data }

